# Composite relations defined by xRy

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let R be the relation defined on $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ defined by $xRy$ if and only if $x < y$. 
$R$ can be written as $\{(x, y) | y − x > 0\}$.

How do I find the composite relation $R^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$? Written in the form above.. I don't know where to start! Or even how to find the transitive closure after!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think $R^n$ is the set of ordered pairs $(x, y)$ such that $y-x\geq n$. Also, $<$ is already transitive, so it's its own transitive closure. $R^n$ is also transitive.

Comment: So for example, R squared would be y - x >= 2?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align}
\mathsf R & = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb Z^+\,^2 \mid y-x>0\}
\\[1ex] & = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb Z^+\,^2 \mid x < y\}
\\[2ex] \mathsf R^2  & = \mathsf R\circ \mathsf R 
\\[1ex] & = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb Z^+\,^2 \mid \exists z\in\mathbb Z^+ : (x,z)\in \mathsf R \wedge (z,y)\in \mathsf R\}
\\[1ex] & = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb Z^+\,^2 \mid \exists z\in\mathbb Z^+: x<z \wedge z<y\}
\\[1ex] & = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb Z^+\,^2 \mid x<y+1\}
\\[1ex] & \; \vdots
\\[2ex] \mathsf R^n & = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb Z^+\,^2 \mid y-x>n-1\}
\\[1ex] & = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb Z^+\,^2 \mid y-x\geq n\} 
\end{align}$